# Upgrade issue to Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I keep getting an error when starting my Grails application after I upgraded from Grails 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 . The full error can be read here: http://pastebin.com/UXQ34JKD

```
2014-10-31 16:26:32 ERROR [context.GrailsContextLoaderListener] Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
        ... 4 more
```

It shows an `Association references unmapped class: java.util.List`

It doesn't say what domain class or any really helpful information. I've tried removing some domain classes and trying to figure what the cause is, but it's large application and I have been unsuccessful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for figuring out where this is being triggered and how to fix it?

Comment: I have seen this error already with older versions of Grails...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Finding out what's wrong

The first thing you need to do is to find out which field(s) cause the issue. Likely it'll be any field *in a domain class* declared as a `List`.

In my case it was easy to find them, because the project is on very early stage and there is not too much domains.

However, I found a [possible solution](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Fork-mode-not-including-resources-tp4658130p4658138.html) to narrow down the possible culprits set.

The interesting part is:

> What sucks is the only good way to figure out where they are is to set a breakpoint on line 436 of AbstractGrailsDomainBinder and look at the state of affairs

### Fixing the issue

When you find the improper fields, it's time to implement a workaround.

Let's assume that our culprit was `List authors` in a domain class like:

```
class Book {
   List<Integer> authors // keeps author ids
}
```

We need to get rid of the list, of course, so the solution would be something like:

```
class Book {

    static transients = ['authors']

    String authorIds

    public void setAuthors(List<Integer> authorList) {
        this.authorIds = authorList ? authorList.join(";") : ''
    }

    public List<Integer> getAuthors() {
        return authorIds?.split(";")?.collect { it.toInteger() } ?: []
    }

}
```

### Possible side effect

I noticed that the setter needs to be called *explicitly* to work.

I'm quite sure that in previous Grails version the following code would call the setter:

```
new Book(authors: [1, 2, 3])
```

But it looks like in Grails 2.4.4 it needs to be done like:

```
def book = new Book()
book.setAuthors([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Well, I don't really consider it a workaround. I just don't think using `List` as a field in a domain class is a good practice at all. But of course I'm open to any suggestions. Please, provide yours.

Comment: Why is this a workaround if Grails says that it supports List of primitive types? http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCollectionTypes

Comment: Well, Grails provides a few features that are actually not the best in real world usage, e.x. hasMany (because of performance) or binding request params directly to domain objects (because of security). The fact it's supported doesn't mean it's the best practice...

Answer (score 10):

You also **need to specify the hasMany map**. It seems that it is not more sufficient to just add `List<DomainClassName> listName` 
in your **Domain-Class**

you also need to **add**

```
static hasMany = [
        listName: DomainClassName
]
```

at least it works for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try to replace problematic `List` interface with something that is real class, for example `ArrayList`